# Banner with images and text resize without changing on resize

Tags: html, css, image, text, resize

I'm trying to create a banner featuring some services I provide, the image below is exactly how I want it (desktop view) but when I resize the browser the text gets pushed underneath the image and is hidden by over elements of the page overlapping.

How do I make it so the image and text resize with the browser and looks exactly the same as it does on desktop?

I created an example on here http://jsfiddle.net/b7a8cvLb/4/

And my CSS

```
.info_banner {
background-color:white;
max-width:1166px;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
text-align:center;
font-size:1em;
height:65px;

}

.info_block {
display:inline-block;
width:20%;
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width:2px;
border-right-color:#F8F8F8;
height:65px;
vertical-align: text-top;
}

.info_block img {
max-width:100% !important;
height:auto;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}

.info_block h5  {
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;   
}
```

If needs be I can set the images to display:none at a certain browser width but I'd prefer to avoid doing this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see your images are already scaling down, if you want to scale down your text too you'll need to step it down using [media queries.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Hope that helps!